# Using exception handler to extend the functionality of default methods (Python taken as example)

Tags: python, exception

So, I'm new to programming and my question is:

Is it considered a **bad** practice to use an exception handler to override error-message-behaviour of default methods of a programming language with custom functionality? I mean, is it ethically correct to use something like this (Python):

```
def index(p, val):
    try:
        return p.index(val)
    except ValueError:
        return -1
```

Maybe I wasn't precise enough. What I meant is: is it a normal or not-recommended practice to consider thrown exceptions (well, I guess it's not applicable everywhere) as legit and valid case-statements?

Like, the idea of the example given above is not to make a custom error message, but to suppress possible errors happening without warning neither users nor other program modules, that something is going wrong.

Comment: Well it is perfectly fine until you are not concerned with the exact error.. And you know why your error will occur.'

Comment: *"... is it ethicaly correct ..."* Well, most programmers don't hold exception handling in such high regard as to consider their usage ethically correct or incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that doing something like this is OK as long as you use function names which make it clear that the user isn't using a built-in.  If the user thinks they're using a builtin and all of a sudden `index` returns -1, imagine the bugs that could happen ... They do:

```
a[index(a,'foo')]
```

and all of a sudden they get the last element in the list (which isn't `foo`).

---

As a very important rule though, *Only handle exceptions that you know what to do with*.  Your example above does this nicely.  Kudos.

Comment: @Vleseg -- That's kind of a stupid example since `a[a.index('foo')]` really just gets `foo` or raises a `ValueError` if it isn't in the list.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly fine but depends on what kind of condition you are checking. It is the developers responsibility to check for these conditions. Some exceptions are fatal for the program and some may not. All depends on the context of the method.

Answer (score 1):

With a language like python, I would argue it is much better to give a custom error message for the function than the generic `ValueError` exception.
However, for your own applications, having this functionality inside your methods can make code easier to read and maintain.

For other languages, the same is true, but you should try and make sure that you don't mimick another function with a different behaviour, whilst hiding the Exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

If you know where exactly your errors will occur and the cause of error too, then there is nothing wrong with such kind of handling. Becaues you are just taking appropriate action for something wrong happening, that you know can happen .

So, `For E.g`: - If you are trying to divide two numbers, and you know that `if the denominator is 0`, then you can't divide, then in that case you can use a custom message to denote the problem.